# Confusion related to marginal precision

Tags: normal-distribution, covariance

I was reading this book where it was mentioned that if my gaussian distribution has unit marginal precision, the covariance matrix equals the correlation matrix. I didn't quite get it. Any clarifications will be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

If the gaussians have unit marginal precision, they have unit variance and unit standard deviations as well. The trick is that the covariance matrix can be expressed as a correlation matrix pre- and post-multiplied by a diagonal matrix of standard deviations. With $\Sigma$ the covariance matrix and $\Omega$ the correlation matrix:

$\boldsymbol{\sigma} I \,\, \Omega \,\, \boldsymbol{\sigma} I ~=~ \Sigma$

In the case you described, these diagonal matrices are identity matrices, which means that the covariance and correlation matrices are identical.